package.json dependency of Angular lib via github not building
I have my package.json file dependency set like this:
"dependencies":{
    "sharethis-angular": "github:crumbyshirt/sharethis-angular#npm-build",
}

The library has a 'preinstall' script on it:
"preinstall": "ng build sharethis-angular",

Running that script works. It outputs this:
ng build sharethis-angular

Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'sharethis-angular'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
✔ Writing FESM bundles
✔ Copying assets
✔ Writing package manifest
✔ Built sharethis-angular

When I add that library as a dependency in my project and run npm install on my project it appears to start working, but then I get this error:
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ng build sharethis-angular
npm ERR! Building Angular Package
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
npm ERR! Building entry point 'sharethis-angular'
npm ERR! ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
npm ERR! - Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
npm ERR! ✔ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
npm ERR! ✖
npm ERR! Could not resolve "./lib/inline-share-buttons/inline-share-buttons.component" from "dist/sharethis-angular/esm2022/public-api.mjs"

What is going wrong with the library build when pulled in via github as a dependency?
I've confirmed that both the library being imported and my project are running Angular 17.3.5.
I originally named the script 'build' rather than 'preinstall' that didn't make a difference.
I had to add a peer dependency to my package to even get this far. This one:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "ng-packagr": "17.3.0"
  }

